# What kind of activities which we receive from onedrive API on editing of a ppt file. Why it doesnt show 'FileModified' Operation?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the API (subscription URI ) `https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{{TenantID}}/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2021-03-30T10:46:22&endTime=2021-03-30T10:47:27` to detect the changes in my drive.
From which we get the results in

`https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/f43eddbb-b83c-46b3-9a9d-722e890a5fdb/activity/feed/audit/20210330104635032000020$20210330104720587000490$audit_sharepoint$Audit_SharePoint$na0022`

I do not get 'FileModified' operation on my results from the ppt file changes. What are the obvious ways to know if the file in my onedrive has changed through API polling?

Comment: is it for Onedrive for business or Onedrive for personal>

Comment: @Dev this is Onedrive for business

Comment: Thanks. If you're using OneDrive for Business, you can subscribe to only the root folder. Change notifications are sent for the requested types of changes on the subscribed folder, or any file, folder, or other driveItem instances in its hierarchy. You cannot subscribe to drive or driveItem instances that are not folders, such as individual files. For more info you can [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).